# Несколько элементов document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function show_hide_all() 
{ 
   var obj = document.getElementById("comments"); 
   if (obj.style.display == "none") obj.style.display = ""; 
   else obj.style.display = "none"; 
   return false; 
} 
</script>
<span onClick="return show_hide_all()" class='precommets'>Комментарии</span>
```

Мне нужно 3 таких элемента (comments), что бы не писать весь скрипт 3 раза, можно ли в функцию `show_hide_all` добавить еще 2 элемента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас в html коде несколько элементов с одинаковыми идентификаторами - ненадо удивляться что `document.getElementById("lolId")` не вернет вам массив, javascript не имеет понятия о том что вы не знаете что несколько элементов с одинаковыми идентификаторами быть не должно. Перепишите `id` атрибут на `class` атрибут, тогда просто можно будет сделать примерно так, так сделать "по хорошему":

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       onload = function() {

       //     pure js
       function changeDisplay() {
            if (obj.style.display == "none") obj.style.display = ""; 
            else obj.style.display = "none";
            return false;
       }

       var comments = document.getElementsByClassName('comments');
       // тогда можно будет пробежаться по всем элементам в цикле
       for( var i=0; i<comments.length; ++i ) {
            var obj = comments[i];
            obj.onclick = changeDisplay;
       }
  }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  // prototype version =)
  Event.observe(window,"load", function(){

      function changeDisplay() {
            if (obj.style.display == "none") obj.style.display = ""; 
            else obj.style.display = "none";
            return false;
      }

      $$(".comments").each(function(el){
          el.onclick = changeDisplay;
          //     или
          Event.observe(el, "click", changeDisplay);
      })

  })
  </script>
```

Ну или просто переписать функцию

```
       // тогда не обязательно переписывать идентификаторы
       // но надо понимать что несколько элементов с одинаковыми `id`
       //                                                        это бред!
       function changeDisplay() {
            if (this.style.display == "none") this.style.display = ""; 
            else this.style.display = "none";
            return false;
       }
```

Если я правильно понял задачу, если же при клике надо менять display всех элементов:

```
       function changeDisplay() {
           var comments = document.getElementsByClassName('comments');
           // тогда можно будет пробежаться по всем элементам в цикле
           for( var i=0; i<comments.length; ++i ) {
               var obj = comments[i];
               obj.onclick = changeDisplay;
           }
       }
```

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо!!!

Comment: принять ответ - зеленая галочка =)

Answer (score -1):

Допустим, нужно вывести на экран несколько рисунков с идентификаторами mym, mam, mim.
Создаете скрипт:

```
 <script>
    x=['mym','mam', 'mim']
    function WW(x){for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    document.getElementById(x[i]).style.display ='block'}
    setTimeout("WW(x)",500)
    </script>
    В body
    перечисляете рисунки (привожу код для одного рисунка):
    <div id="mym" style="display:none; margin-top:15"><p align=right><img SRC='18.jpg'  width=150 height=100>
    </div>
```

Задержка позволяет выводить рисунки группами в разное время и совершать над ними действия (например, убирать через какое-то время с экрана)